# UINavigationBar appearance error in IOS 5

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ios5

I want to make a custom UINavigationBar with a drop shadow.
Doing so:

```
UIImage *barImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"navbar2.png"]resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)]; // OK
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:barImage forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];  // OK

[[UINavigationBar appearance] setShadowColor:[UIColor blackColor]]; // Error
```

What is wrong?

Can I do this thing with "appearance"?

Thanx!

Comment: You might have to subclass UINavigationbar to add shadow. I am not sure if it has setShadowColor property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UINavigationBar` doesn't have a shadow color. It has a shadow image or if you want to set the text shadow, use `titleTextAttributes`.

Comment: [[UINavigationBar appearance] setShadowImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navbar2.png"]]; ERROR - [_UIAppearance setShadowImage:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8839c40
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[_UIAppearance setShadowImage:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8839c40'

Comment: like I said. there is no shadow image to set.